# Attach GDB to process ID in TUI mode?

Tags: gdb

I am trying to attach to a running process in TUI mode to see the code etc. The code is compiled with `-g`. 
I understand at the moment I try attach I may be in some C standard code with no debugging symbols but how can I get back into the "main application" to see the code?

```
gdb --pid=1111 -tui
```

I assume that should work (whereby 1111 is just a dummt pid for this question)?

Comment: what do u mean by get back into the "main application" to see the code?

Answer (score 0):

Issue the command "up" (to climb up in the call stack of the program) as often as it needs to get back into your code (that is the code having debug info along with it) then issue the command "b [line]" to the next [line] in your source, then issues the command "continue" to continue with program execution and see as the debugger stops at the break point you just set in your code.